# How to edit URL labels in blogger without lose any post in there?

Tags: html, css, blogs

in my blogger labels URL like that
https://www.ddfreetech.com/search/label/CPA%20Marketing?&max-results=5

I want to change it like that
https://www.ddfreetech.com/search/label/CPA-Marketing

how to solve it?
Thank You

Comment: %20 is a space, not `-`, and you're also excluding your `max-results` variable. Are you planning on hard-coding that to 5? Are you decoding this URL manually (.htaccess maybe?) or are you relying on a plugin to do it for you?

Comment: I use blogger and this is html5 CSS JS